# How can I customize the modebar in plotly (preferably in R)?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

In particular, I am looking for a way to hide all buttons except the download image button. I tried to use the config argument but so far only managed to hide the entire modebar using *displayModeBar = F*. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you are looking for:

```
plot_ly(economics, x = ~pop) %>% 
  config(displaylogo = FALSE, collaborate = FALSE,
         modeBarButtonsToRemove = c(
           'sendDataToCloud', 'autoScale2d', 'resetScale2d', 'toggleSpikelines',
           'hoverClosestCartesian', 'hoverCompareCartesian',
           'zoom2d','pan2d','select2d','lasso2d','zoomIn2d','zoomOut2d'
         ))
```

[image]

Since possible buttons are going to depend on the type of graph, keep in mind [this](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/components/modebar/buttons.js) list.

Comment: @ Julius Thank you very much. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: the 'config' is not producing a plot but a text (class request) that descibes the options.